# What is the snippet library that RStudio frequently tries to autocomplete to?

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

RStudio frequently tries to auto-complete to some "snippet" package. I cannot find this anywhere in my list of loaded packages or in any R documentation. What is it? Is it some quirk of RStudio?

[image]

Comment: It's not a package, it's an IDE feature. See here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can edit the Snippets:
RStudio: Tools -> Global options -> Code.

Definition is given by Ian Campbell in his comment.
[image]